What are all the ways to combine Recall Knowledge with another action?
Consider the hypothetical: A prospective GM told us the campaign will feature many, many strange monsters that will absolutely murder us if we don't play into their puzzle-like nature. However, we players all share a terrible allergy to bad action economy that will kill us if we make a normal Recall Knowledge check.
To avoid both horrible fates, we need to build characters that can combine a Recall Knowledge with another action - feats like (off the top of my head) "hunt prey and recall knowledge", "exploit vulnerability and recall knowledge", "strike and recall knowledge", etc.

Search: Recall Knowledge; Filter: Type/Action = Action OR Feat
Combined Actions

Exploit Vulnerability - Thaumaturge; Includes some effects of Recall Knowledge

Diverse Lore - Thaumaturge; Exploit Vulnerability now includes full effects of Recall Knowledge


Educated Assessment - Pathfinder Agent; Recall Knowledge and Battle Assessment
Magus Analysis - Magus; Recall Knowledge and recharge your Spellstrike
Thoughtful Reload - Gunslinger; Recall Knowledge and Reload
Known Weakness - Investigator; Recall Knowledge and Devise a Stratagem
Monster Hunter - Ranger; Hunt Prey and Recall Knowledge
Instructive Strike - Thaumaturge; Strike and Recall Knowledge on a success
Combat Assessment - Fighter/Butterfly Blade; Strike and Recall Knowledge on a success
Uzunjati Recollection - Magaambyan Attendant; Recall Knowledge and Uzunjati Storytelling
Practiced Opposition - Lastwall Sentry; Undead only; Recall Knowledge and Strike, 1/day per creature

Free Knowledge Checks
While not exactly what you asked for, these address your concern - Knowledge checks that can be made without spending an Action at all.

Expeditious Inspection - Investigator; 10m cooldown
Automatic Knowledge - 1/rd, must use Assurance value
Enigma's Knowledge - Bard; 1/rd, must use Assurance value
Diverse Recognition - Pathfinder Agent; must have used Recall Knowledge already
Additional Recollection - Ranger; must have used Recall Knowledge already
Recognize Threat - Pathfinder Agent; at the start of an encounter
Slayer's Identification - Undead Slayer; Undead only; at the start of an ecnounter
Diabolic Ceritude - Hellknight Armiger; Devil only; 1/rd
Dualistic Synergy - Halcyon Speaker; after casting an Arcane spell from a spell slot
Fountain of Secrets - Shisk; 1/rd

Honorable Mentions - Lots of Recall Knowledge
Want to get all of your Recall Knowledge results at once for less actions? Here are some ways to do that...

True Hypercognition - Bard/Loremaster; 5 Recall Knowledge checks
Incredible Recollection - Eldritch Researcher; 5 Recall Knowledge checks
Reason Rapidly - Investigator; 5 Recall Knowledge checks
All the Time in the World - Investigator (Capstone); 9 Actions to spend on mental actions such as Recall Knowledge


A lovely list but I wish to add one more: Diverse Lore moves Exploit Vulnerability from "some of the information" to "all of the information, and then some"

Added, but converted this to a community answer so anyone can add future findings.
